# Duvidas sobre Stored Function

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Oque é uma Stored Function, qual sua sintaxe básica ? Como e onde utilizar uma Stored Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sintaxe basica de uma Function em MySQL :

```
delimiter $    
CREATE FUNCTION nome_da_funcao (parametros)  
RETURNS INT  -- pode retornar qualquer tipo de dado 
BEGIN
    -- codigo
       return valor;
END$

delimiter;
```

A função funciona para fazer alterações ou métodos que poupariam o trabalho de programação.

> Ex. Descontar determinado produto, Calcular imposto, etc.

Para chamar a função você pode tanto fazer uma chamada simples :

```
select funcao();
```

Pode também atribuir o valor de retorno para uma variável em MySQL :

```
declare valor;
set valor = funcao();
```

Existem também as Stored Procedures, que basicamente não retornam valor, mas são chamadas por um comando diferente:

```
call procedure();
```

Mais informações :

> [Criando Stored Procedures MySQL](https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/2088/criando_stored_procedures_no_mysql)
>   [MySQL Stored Functions](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/)